# Java - How to extract text from an XLS which has wrong format/extension issue?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf, hssfworkbook

I have an excel (`.xls`) file - `Export.xls`.

When I manually try to open it, I get the following message:

"**`The file format and extension of 'Export.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway`**?"

If I click on 'Yes' and proceed, the file opens. Then, if I '`Save As`' `Excel 97-2003 Workbook (*.xls)`, the file is saved and the next time I open it I don't get the above error message.

Now, my need is to do this via Java code. Because due to restrictions, I cannot fix it manually before I run the Java program.

**My working code for a non-corrupted (regular) file below:**

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.ExcelExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

    HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(expFile));
    String expFileText = new ExcelExtractor(expWorkBook).getText();
    System.out.println("Export xls file text: " + expFileText);
```

This works fine on a regular `xls` file. However, for the above file (if I haven't manually saved it with a different format), the Java program throws the below error:

**`Invalid header signature; read 0x6D78206C6D74683C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document`**

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The file content is not in sync with the file name/extension.

To find out what the content really is, you could run `file Export.xls` in a Linux system (see [man file](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html)). Do that with the file before and after opening/saving it in Excel.

Comment: I noticed that the mime type for this .xls file is listed as Export.xls: HTML document, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: The mime type is a hint but also no guarantee. Check the content.

Answer (score 1):

That seems plain text "mx lm...".

Often CSV text files are given an .xls extension so the browser  opens the file with Excel.

Rename the file as .txt and check the charset encoding, and read it with the correct charset. Maybe a CSV reader.

Comment: I checked the charset encoding of the file. It is UTF-8.

Comment: I checked the contents of the file. It's not CSV. It's an excel format data, with tables and rows.

Comment: Did you really try it by changing the file extension to .txt? "mx lm..." is weird though.

Comment: Yes. I did. Pardon me, where does it say "mx lm..."?

Comment: The hexadecimal codes 6D = thirteenth small letter = m, 78  = 24th letter = x. Hence my assumption that the file is plain text, faked to be opened by Excel.

Comment: I noticed that the mime type for this .xls file is listed as Export.xls: HTML document, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: I am wondering if this is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Still the root cause is that you are trying to open a file as OLE2 document while it is not. The filename is misleading, and the mime type is further indication something is wrong. But ultimately you need to check the content of the document.